# Social Media Icons in Footer

Tags: css, wordpress, icons, footer, social-media

I use wordpress and want to add social media icons to my footer. What I did so far is to add the following code to the footer.php:

```
<div id="social-buttons">
<a href="http://twitter.com/veda_vit" rel="me"><img title="veda-vit.de bei Twitter" src="http://veda-vit.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Twitter.svg" alt="Twitter Button" width="24" height="24" />
</a>
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/vedavit.de" rel="me"><img title="veda-vit.de bei Facebook" src="http://veda-vit.de/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/Facebook.svg" alt="Facebook Button" width="24" height="24" />
</a>
</div>
```

And additionally I added the following css code to place the icons on the right:

```
#social-buttons a img {
margin: 10px 12px 0 0;
float: right;
}
```

It works so far, but the icons are placed on a second line (see here: www.veda-vit.de).

What can I do to place the copyright and the icons on one line? I tried already everything, but couldn't solve the problem. Can anybody help me, please?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this CSS code and it will work nicely

```
#social-buttons {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  top: -9px;
}
```

[image]

You can edit it more by changing top position.

Comment: Just one more question: How can I increase the distance between the two icons?

Comment: @pradhana add `margin-right: 10px` to the `#social-buttons a`

Comment: By doing so it just increases the distance between the second icon and the edge on the right. You know what I mean? I just want to increase the distance between the two icons.

Comment: I guess I found a solution: #social-buttons img { margin: 0 0 0 12px; }

Comment: @pradhana Yes that can work, you can also target first **child** under element #social-buttons and only modify its margin. You should learn about box model in CSS: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp